# Php cURL works on site but returns nothing on another

Tags: php, curl

Php curl_exec works here: http://membership.oqmhandbook.com/order.php

but same code doesn't work here: http://wecallyouleads.com/order.php

any help would be appreciated..!!

my code is

```
$dsc_msg = '[my xml request]';

$dsc_header = array("POST /send/interchange HTTP/1.1",
   "Host: lightning.instascreen.net",
   "Content-Type: text/xml, charset=utf-8‏",
   "SOAPAction: \"https://lightning.instascreen.net/send/interchange\""
  );

  $ch = curl_init("https://lightning.instascreen.net/send/interchange");
  if ($ch == FALSE) {
   echo "Connecting to createsend failed\n";
  }
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $dsc_header);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dsc_msg);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);    

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  echo "Return XML:\n$result\n";
```

Comment: maybe curl_exec is not enabled on wecallyouleads.com

Comment: Check for cURL Errors.  After your `curl_exec`, put in `if(curl_errno($ch)) {echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);}` and see if that spits anything out.

Comment: @Quixrick i've added that, now its giving me an error check here:
 http://wecallyouleads.com/order.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, it looks like it is attempting to verify the SSL (which it absolutely should), but it cannot.  Really, to fix this, you need to make sure the SSL is in proper order.

If you absolutely cannot, you can try adding in this to see if it makes a difference.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

This is not really good practice and this article on how doing stuff like this makes cURL the most dangerous code in the world is really good.  Scroll down to section 7 (on page 7 of the PDF) for some good examples of what NOT To do.

[The Most Dangerous Code in the World:
Validating SSL Certificates in Non-Browser Software](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf)